# ListView: Items are not correctly added

Tags: c#, listview, listviewitem

I have 3 coloumns (1996, 1997, 1998), which come from a DB. I want to show them in a listview.

My Problem is, it shows all first column data perfectly, but the second column data starts after end of first column. Also, the last two columns come together.

```
{
     listView1.Items.Clear();
     SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(tools.ConnectionString);
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("alti", cnn);
     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", comboBox1.SelectedItem);
     cnn.Open();
     SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

     while (dr.Read())
     {
         int yil = Convert.ToInt32(dr["yil"].ToString());
         ListViewItem lvitem = new ListViewItem();

         if (yil == 1996)
         {
             lvitem.Text =(dr["OrderID"].ToString() + "--" + dr["Fiyat"].ToString() );
         }
         else if (yil == 1997)
         {
             lvitem.SubItems.Add(dr["OrderID"].ToString() + "--" + dr["Fiyat"].ToString());
         }
         else if (yil == 1998)
         {
             lvitem.SubItems.Add(dr["OrderID"].ToString() + "--" + dr["Fiyat"].ToString());                   
         }
             listView1.Items.Add(lvitem);                   
     }
         cnn.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While your question is about legacy `ListView`. For purposes like yours using `ListView` in `VirtualMode` is more suitable (see [`ListView.VirtualMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.virtualmode.aspx)). Also if you wanna try something new and more powerful `BrightIdeasSoftware.ObjectListView` (OLV) which is a third party control is much more better. You can add your items (which will be objects :) in OLV) with less difficulty. Also it has lots of tools for styling. Take a look at it [here](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html).

Comment: ObjectListview looks very useful but bot workng on vs2012:(
and trying to do with listview.virtualmode thanx for that:)

Answer (score 0):

Listview's 1st column is where you make your Items.Add() and the second column and beyond is where you use SubItems.Add(). In other words the seocnd column and beyond is tied up to the second column.

To illustrate it would be like this:

```
ListViewItem itm = listView1.Items.Add('First Column');
itm.SubItems.Add('Second Column');
itm.SubItems.Add('Third Column');
```

Now in your case it's a little bit tricky because multiple records would become multiple columns ala Pivot Table. So, I suggest that gather all the years first of 1996 to 1997 before adding it to listview like:

```
 String for96='',for97='',for98='';

 while (dr.Read())
     {
         int yil = Convert.ToInt32(dr["yil"].ToString());


         if (yil == 1996)
         {
             for96 =(dr["OrderID"].ToString() + "--" + dr["Fiyat"].ToString() );
         }
         else if (yil == 1997)
         {
             for97 = dr["OrderID"].ToString() + "--" + dr["Fiyat"].ToString();
         }
         else if (yil == 1998)
         {
             for98=dr["OrderID"].ToString() + "--" + dr["Fiyat"].ToString();                
         }
         if (!String.IsNotNullOrEmpty(for96) && !String.IsNotNullOrEmpty(for97) && !String.IsNotNullOrEmpty(for98))
         {
             ListViewItem itm = new ListViewItem();
             itm = listView1.Items.Add(for96);
             itm.SubItems.Add(for97);          
             itm.SubItems.Add(for98);      

             for96='',for97='',for98='';
         }

     }
```

Comment: shen i use it with last line for96='',for97='',for98='';
it returns 1 row for all coloumns.when delete that line, for96 and for97 repeat same line.

Comment: @onurasan could you show me the actual data of your table? and from there I will revise my answer. Thanks.

Comment: i collect datas from Northwind sample database but query side is working perfectly.now i got 3 array(for96,for97,for98) or list(for96,for97,for98) i need to show them with listview. u can use array or list its up to you:)

Comment: What particular Table are your referring to in Northwind Database? I was looking at it specifically on Orders table bcoz you mentioned OrderID but I could not find **yil** or **fiyat** fields.

Comment: u cant find them cuz i give them randm name.
i create procedure on mssql 
go
alter proc alti
 @name nvarchar(max)=''
as   
select o.OrderID as OrderID,(od.UnitPrice*od.Quantity*(1+od.Discount))as Fiyat,
DATEPART(year,OrderDate) as yil
   
from Categories as c inner join Products as p 
 on c.CategoryID=p.CategoryID inner join [Order Details] as od
 on od.ProductID=p.ProductID inner join Orders as o
 on o.OrderID=od.OrderID 
where c.CategoryName=@name and (DATEPART(year,OrderDate)  between 1996 and 1998)
order by 1 desc

Comment: Thank you @onurasan. And looking at the output there is no year beyond 1996. So, how exactly do you want this records to be displayed? OrderID, Fiyat and Yil? And curiously why do you  need to test the year whether it is 1996 or 1997 or 1998? What is exactly your purpose for that? Do you want it to be displayed in separate columns for one Order for example? Say 11077, 40.50, 1996, 50.30, 1997, 60.50, 1998? or just one record at a time like 11077, 40.50, 1996?